# sendfile() doesn't work to copy normal text file

Tags: text, file, sendfile

The problem with sendfile is it can't copy two text files using the file fds.
The error is EINVAL.
// Descriptor is not valid or locked, or an mmap()-like operation is not available for in_fd.

What does this really mean ?

From the man page of sendfile ( man sendfile ) I found this statement. Not sure if it will work to copy two regular files or not.

Presently  (Linux  2.6.9):  in_fd,  must correspond to a file which supports mmap()-like operations (i.e., it cannot be a socket); and
       out_fd must refer to a socket.

```
   Applications may wish to fall back to read(2)/write(2) in the case where sendfile() fails with EINVAL or ENOSYS.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea behind `sendfile()` is to quickly send a file over a socket (think web servers).  Regular files can be `mmap()`ed, but are not sockets, so it's blowing up when you hand it a regular file as the destination.

Comment: man page if sendfile also suggested the same. now I am using std. c++ way. ofstream << ifstream.rdbuf(). Is there any better way even if it is Linux specific ?

Comment: Not really.  It's not generally the OS's place to provide a "copy this file here" system call.